# Google Appengine deploy error (Unknowne Error in deployment)

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

Google Appengine deployment fails with `Googlesdkerror: Unknowne Error in deployment`, yes typo included.

```
2014-05-15 11:22:48,051 - root - INFO - Send: /api/appversion/create, params={'version': '1', 'app_id': 'app-id'}
2014-05-15 11:22:48,894 - root - INFO - Send: /api/appversion/cloneblobs, params={'version': '1', 'app_id': 'app-id'}
2014-05-15 11:22:50,145 - root - INFO - Send: /api/appversion/cloneblobs, params={'version': '1', 'app_id': 'app-id'}
2014-05-15 11:22:50,868 - root - INFO - Send: /api/appversion/cloneblobs, params={'version': '1', 'app_id': 'app-id'}
2014-05-15 11:22:51,705 - root - INFO - Send: /api/appversion/cloneblobs, params={'version': '1', 'app_id': 'app-id'}
2014-05-15 11:22:52,576 - root - INFO - Send: /api/appversion/cloneblobs, params={'version': '1', 'app_id': 'app-id'}
2014-05-15 11:22:53,264 - root - INFO - Send: /api/appversion/clonefiles, params={'version': '1', 'app_id': 'app-id'}
2014-05-15 11:22:54,365 - root - INFO - HTTP Error (HTTP Error 409: Conflict)
2014-05-15 11:22:54,366 - root - INFO - Send: /api/appversion/rollback, params={'version': '1', 'app_id': 'app-id'}
2014-05-15 11:22:54,743 - root - ERROR - Unknowne Error in deployment
2014-05-15 11:22:54,743 - root - ERROR - Unknowne Error in deployment
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4043, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ubuntu/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4032, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(usrargs).Run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2532, in Run
    raise Googlesdkerror("Unknowne Error in deployment")
Googlesdkerror: Unknowne Error in deployment
```

This error occurs approximately 40% of the time.

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Are you seeing this intermittently, where it will fail once, then work immediately after that? Have you tried doing a appcfg.py rollback to see if that clears up the problem?

Comment: Yes we are seeing this intermittently. Yes appcfg rollback usually works, but it becomes a problem in automated environments where deploys are run via scripts